# Why isn't Angular respecting the type Date explicitly required in the method signature?

Tags: angular, date, types

I'm surprised that the following throws an error. It seems that the type of *input* provided is *string* and not, as I'd expect *Date*. How come?

```
static datify(input: Date, format?: string): string {
  if (!input)
    return "";

  const yyyy = input.getFullYear() + "";
  ...
}
```

I got it working by explicitly creating an object of type *Date* but it confuses me to have to do it. Also, I fear that by adding this instantiation, I've introduced a bunch of others issues that I'm overseeing at the moment.

```
static datify(input: Date, format?: string): string {
  if (!input)
    return "";

  input = new Date(input);

  const yyyy = input.getFullYear() + "";
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is a weakly typed programming language. This means that no type checking is done during runtime. Since typescript gets compiled into Javascript, the variable type "Date" is not being checked during runtime, means, it can still be any type.

Comment: So what's the point of the hard typing all the variables using TypeScript? I get that during **run-time** we only have the transpiled crappy JS but during **compile-time** or even **dev-time**, I'd like to get some warning or hint. Otherwise, I see no point specifying that it's a *Date* type if it can be *Donkey* type or whatever else... (I resolved it by explicitly converting to *Date* while creating the parent object but I should be warned/hinted if I omit that step, hence simply assigning a *string* formatted as a date.)

Comment: I get what you are saying. What IDE are you using? I strongly recommend to use Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/). Are you using Angular-CLI (https://cli.angular.io/)? Do you use the TSLint plugin for Visual Studio Code (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint)? The combination of these tools provide syntax and style guide checks during **compile-time** and **dev-time**, I think that is exactly what you may be looking for! Additionally, using these tools, you get Visual Studio like IntelliSense providing you with hints about the methods and properties.

Comment: Hehehe, sadly, it's **yes** on all the three. I'm using VS Code since 18 months, NgCli since 6 months and I've started linting my code 3 months ago. Darn... (On the other hand, it's nice to know that I'm using the right combo of tools, so thanks anyway.)